# 404 ON BROWERS BUT 200 ON PYTHON

Tags: python, server, get, python-requests, http-status-code-404

```
import requests

req = requests.get('http://danluanvn.blogspot.se')

print(req)
```

this script return 200 but access by browers return 404. Please help me find out the problem and how to rosolve this problem.

Comment: I don't see 404 from Chrome

Comment: Works with Chrome for me. Do you have any proxy settings in Chrome or maybe other strange configuration? Does it work with other browsers?

Comment: Hi bro,
this web is blocked on my network, so all browsers can't access. but i was test by pycharm. it's response 200